# Problem while adding Data to Core Data - nil is not a legal parameter

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm getting this error:

> 2018-09-08 17:53:36.795035+0200 Movie Roulette[826:263749] [error]
>   error:  Failed to load model named ett CoreData: error:  Failed to
>   load model named ett 2018-09-08 17:53:36.796536+0200 Movie
>   APP[826:263749] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a
>   legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name
>   'MovieData''

Maybe some of you can help me to solve this problem. I have searched and read that I must create an NSManagedObjectContext. I have created this in my func but I'm still getting this error.

```
func save(name: String) {
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }

    // 1
    let managedContext =
        appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    // 2
    let entity =
        NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "MovieData",
                                   in: managedContext)!

    let MovieDT = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                  insertInto: managedContext)

    // 3
    MovieDT.setValue(name, forKeyPath: "titel")

    // 4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        movieArray.append(MovieDT)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but never `guard` `AppDelegate`. Force unwrap it. Your app won't even reach this line if `AppDelegate` was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can only happen if the model name changed , here in `AppDelegate`

```
let container = NSPersistentcontainer(name:"thisMayChanged")
container.loadPersistentStores......
```

it's clear in crash

> CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named **ett**

and project name is Movie APP

> Movie APP[826:263749]

you changed original name to ett as by default it should be **Movie_APP**

Comment: sure the entity named **MovieData** contains **titel** ??

Comment: Thank you for ur help.I have solved this problem.Sometimes I should just read some errors more than 1 time :-D